# Does it make sense to use MeteorJS to create non-Meteor website login?

Tags: meteor, jekyll, meteor-accounts

I have a JekyllRB site that has both free and premium content. I want to protect my premium content with a simple email-only login (also captures email for marketing). I haven't found a membership or login system that is simple, without more bells than I need.

I'm also learning MeteorJS and after seeing the robust user auth/login systems, was wondering if it makes sense and is possible to create a log in app in Meteor that acts as the site's login system.

Can websites have added Meteor apps? Thinking of the polling app from Scotch.io and adding it to my site. That kind of thing.

I'd also want to connect with my MailChimp account to automatically add the new user email to my list...have to study their API to do that so manually adding them is fine at this point.

A good idea or not? If possible, any advice on an approach for a Meteor noob?

Thanks!

Comment: I went to a hackathon this past weekend for LaunchKey.. Its a series of tools than enables login via mobile multifactor authentication.  You can integrate multifactor authentication for your site for free.  Good for you, safer for your users (you don't have to store either email address or passwords), easy to implement, and its free.  check out   https://launchkey.com/MFA  (all the interfaces are listed @ https://github.com/LaunchKey)

Comment: It will likely be painful to bolt Meteor on to an existing site, especially for making auth actually secure. It might be easier to put your premium content on your Meteor site or even all of it.

Comment: @zipzit ... thanks, I'll check that out & see if it meets my needs.

Comment: @Michel Floyd ... that's kinda what I figured, bolting them together would be tough; hadn't thought of putting the premium stuff on a Meteor site. Interesting approach; I'll investigate.